# Creating an object of a class whose field is a set of objects of another class

Tags: python, django

In the Django model lets create a class, eg Ingredients:

```
class IngredientsClass(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Name', max_length=50, default='')
    package_price = models.FloatField()
    package_amount = models.FloatField()
    supplier = models.ForeignKey(SupplierClass)
    price = models.FloatField()
```

Now lets make some product from the ingredients

```
class DishClass(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Name', max_length=50, default='')
    price = models.FloatField()
    ingredients = models.***???***
```

And here is a problem... In the field *ingredients* of an DishClass object can be different amount of ingredients from one to thousand.

How do I need to set up the field *ingredients*?

Comment: This is a many-to-many relationship, because as you identified, a dish can contain many ingredients - and an ingredient can also be related to many different dishes. I don't use django so can't confidently answer you with a code example, but you probably want to do something like ingredients = models.ManyToManyField(IngredientsClass). Have a read about many to many relationships in django and be sure of what you're doing

Comment: Looks like it is... I read carefully about ManyToManyFeild... Will try it and UPD after

Answer (score 1):

As Matt Smith correctly pointed out in the comments, you are looking for a many to many relationship.

```
ingredients = models.ManyToManyField(IngredientsClass)
```

You can configure the field further by passing in parameters. For a more detailed explenation refer to the [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/models/fields/#manytomanyfield).